# MQ messaging architecture for managing rejected messages

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I am having some difficulty deciding between 2x approaches to managing the rejection of messages on an MQ client. Admittedly, it's more an ideological argument than a technical one.

Consider this: a message (XML) on a queue is read by a client. The client checks the digital signature (and, by extension, whether the message adheres to a certain schema), before further processing. Let's say the verification of the digital signature fails though. I don't want the message to be further processed. It needs to go back to source and be sorted out 'by hand'.

As far as I can see, there are 2x approaches I could take:

**Option 1**

- Client reads message
- Client acknowledges receipt
- Client discovers message is somehow invalid
- Client writes invalid message onto 'reject' queue

  ```
                    CLIENT   MQ CLIENT
                     READ    +-------+        +----+ 
     OUT Q | --- | --------> |PROCESS| -----> |NEXT| 
           | --- |           |MESSAGE|        |STEP| 
           +-----+           +-------+        +----+ 
                                 | 
                                 | 
  REJECT Q | --- | <-------------+ 
           | --- |     FAILURE
           +-----+
  ```

**Option 2**

- Client reads message
- Client discovers message is somehow invalid
- Client does not acknowledge receipt of message
- MRRTY = 0 (?) so QM writes message onto reject Q

  ```
                     CLIENT   MQ CLIENT
                      READ    +-------+        +----+
     OUT Q  | --- | --------> |PROCESS| -----> |NEXT|
            | --- | <-------- |MESSAGE|        |STEP|
            +-----+  FAILURE  +-------+        +----+
               |
               |
               V
  REJECT Q  | --- |
            | --- |
            +-----+
  ```

I'm biased towards Option 2, where the QM is responsible for writing failed messaged onto a reject queue, as it seems to me to be a neater solution. This would also mean that the comms to the client is in one direction only. I understand the CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE is for the receipt of all messages up to point of acknowledgement: Am I misguided in thinking that ACKing per-message would be the mechanism that would allow me to have the QM write failed messaged onto the rejected Q per MRRTY parameter?

Any opinion / discussion re standard patterns / architecture much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain what MRRTY is?

Comment: I think the first solution is much cleaner, the application should handle the application errors, and a malformed message is an application error. The queue manager should only handle transport errors.

Comment: By the way, I don't think you are using IBM WebSphere MQ, do you? It has no MRRTY option, and certainly no mechanism for routing failed messages. You should specify what MQ you are using.

Comment: Using WebSphere MQ. MRRTY is the "max retry" on a message [see here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.con.doc/q082060_.htm)

Comment: MRRTY does exist in WebSphere MQ and is the count of message retries on a channel. Goes hand in hand with MRTMR, the message retry timer. This only exists for receiver type channels and is not applicable for client-server channels,

Comment: Option 1 is the one to go for. There is no mechanism for having the queue manager route a failed message to a side queue. It is the responsibility of the application.

Comment: "The queue manager should only handle transport errors" (Attila) ... "There is no mechanism for having the queue manager route a failed message to a side queue" (Morag) - Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both [Morag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4042083) and [Attila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180950) for their help and input.

What it came down to was essentially this:

> The application should handle the application errors, and a malformed message is an application error. The queue manager should only handle transport errors. ([Attila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4180950))

and this...

> There is no mechanism for having the queue manager route a failed message to a side queue. It is the responsibility of the application. ([Morag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4042083))

So in the case of application errors the client itself will be expected to write failed / malformed messages back onto a separate queue out-of-band.